# Чтение файла и работа с потоком

Tags: java

Есть функция чтения из файла:

```
private  static String read(File in)
{
    String result= "";
    try ( BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in)))
    {

        while (reader.ready())
        {
            result= reader.readLine() + "\n";

        }

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return result;
}
```

Файл представляет собой матрицу:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
```

При чтении я дроблю файл по `"\n"` он берет одну строчку и записывает в `result`, затем я вызываю эту функцию в потоке, который отвечает за чтение:

```
Thread t_1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            str = read(new File("FileName.csv"));
        }
    });
    t_1.start();
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы произошло чтение первой строчки, результат записался в `str`, и строчка поступила на обработку в другой поток, а первый поток начал считывать вторую строчку из файла? Просто сейчас получается, что в `str` подается последняя строчка файла.

Comment: поясните пожалуйста

Comment: Что именно смущает?

Comment: ну что попробовали вы? тут никто готовую программу писать не будет

Comment: Я не знаю как это сделать, поэтому и спрашиваю, то что я пробовал, не работает.

Comment: это называется Producer Consumer, если делать руками, то нужна потокобезопасная очередь, в которую поток, читающий файл, будет складывать строки, а обрабатывающий поток будет их вынимать. Рунет как-то не балует примерами, для затравки можно посмотреть [эту статью](http://java-online.ru/concurrent-queue-block.xhtml#exampleABQ)

Comment: У вас какая-то сложная процедура обработки str? Вставьте в код функцию обработки str после чтения строки и всё. Т.е. получится считал одну строку, обработал, считал следующую, обработал и так далее

Answer (score 0):

На начало создайте класс наследуя от Thread

```
import java.io.*;

public class AsyncTask extends Thread {

private String Localstr;
private Callback callback;

public AsyncTask(Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    read(new File("file.csv"));
}

private String read(File in)
{
    String result= "";
    try ( BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in)))
    {
        while (reader.ready())
        {
            result = reader.readLine() + "\n";

            if (Localstr == null){
                Localstr = result;
                callback.operation(result);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

CallBack интерфейс:

```
public interface Callback {
    void operation(String str);
}
```

И наконец вызов в главном потоке:

```
AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void operation(String str) {
            resultInMainThread = str;
        }
    });
    task.start();
```

Comment: в этом коде `callback.operation` будет выполняться в том потоке, в котором ее вызвали

Comment: @zRrr В точку и возвратит ее в главный поток что пытается добиться автор вопроса

Comment: нет. В лучшем случае он присвоит полю какого-то класса значение `str`. Замените ваши присваивания на `System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() )` и убедитесь, что и цикл чтения и колбек работают в одном треде.